# FAMILY.PY | OOPython

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, object-oriented, game

Simple code where family and person instances can be created. There is a method where any instance of Person can be added to any instance of Family.

```
class Family:
    def __init__(self):
        self.names, self.birthplaces, self.dobs, self.deaths = [], [], [], []


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, birthplace, dob, death=None):
        self.name, self.birthplace, self.dob, self.death = name, birthplace, dob, death

    def add_member_to(self, family_tree):
        family_tree.names.append(self.name)
        family_tree.birthplaces.append(self.birthplace)
        family_tree.dobs.append(self.dob)

        if self.death is None:
            family_tree.deaths.append('N/A')
        else:
            family_tree.deaths.append(self.death)


family = Family()
mike = Person('Michael', 'Nigeria', '06-07-2004')
esther = Person('Esther', 'KC', '03-25-2009')
mike.add_member_to(family)
esther.add_member_to(family)
print(family.dobs)
print(family.names)
print(family.birthplaces)
print(family.deaths)
```

Answer (score 1):

My one improvement would be this line of code

```
if self.death is None:
    family_tree.deaths.append('N/A')
else:
    family_tree.deaths.append(self.death)
```

can be reduced to one line:

```
family_tree.deaths.append('N/A' if self.death is None else self.death)
```

Also, I would recommend keeping all code not in these classes in a [main guard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578335/8968906), so you can import these classes without also running the code in the module.

Answer (score 1):

- `add_member_to` acts on `family_tree` and changes its fields. It is more logical to define the method in the class `Family` as `add_member` instead.
- The `Family` class should directly store a list of `Person`s as a field rather than copying all the information of the family members. Information of members can be directly retrieved from `Person` objects when needed. This avoids the same data being copied redundantly, which adds burden to maintainence (e.g., every change of `Person` information requires a subsequent change in `Family` of the copied information). `names`, `birthplaces`, `dobs`, `deaths` can be defined as class properties and accessed through defined methods.

- `Person` can be defined as a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), which can automatically generate methods such as `__init__` from field definitions. It may be an overkill for this small program but it will be useful for larger classes.